# How to start all sounds at level 0

Tags: windows-7, audio, system-sounds

I want all sounds to start at the lowest volume unless I increase it. This is to apply to all videos, music, ads etc that occasionally startle users by large volume settings. 
If there is such an option for system sounds, that would be of interest too.

Comment: No, there is no such an option in Windows. But maybe you can search/ask at [softwarerecs.SE] – maybe someone has seen some 3rd party software doing what you are looking for.

Comment: Sound level is by Device not application, so there is no way to do what you want in Windows, and asking for 3rd party software solutions is off topic here.

Comment: @Moab "Sound level is by Device not application," I'm not sure this statement is accurate, as Windows 7's mixer shows levels per application. Having said that, controlling the volume of unexpected videos, ads, etc. that are in a browser would be tricky (at best) to detect and control individually.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, sorry for using application, could have used better terminology, but I suppose flash is considered an application but does not show in mixer.

Comment: @Moab It was more the use of "by device" that threw me. ;)